# Difference between "backward kill line" and "unix line discard"

Tags: command-line, emacs, readline

I'm reading the bash man page and memorizing the keyboard shortcuts. `C-x rubout` is bound to `backward kill line`, and `C-u` is bound to `unix line discard`, but the descriptions for these commands look the same.  What is the difference between these commands?

Answer (score 1):

In their [current implementation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/kill.c?id=ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814), these two functions seem to do more or less the same thing, except that `backward-kill-line` can take a negative prefix argument, while `unix-line-discard` ignores the prefix argument.

```
/* Here is C-u doing what Unix does.  You don't *have* to use these
   key-bindings.  We have a choice of killing the entire line, or
   killing from where we are to the start of the line.  We choose the
   latter, because if you are a Unix weenie, then you haven't backspaced
   into the line at all, and if you aren't, then you know what you are
   doing. */
int
rl_unix_line_discard (int count, int key)
{
  if (rl_point == 0)
    rl_ding ();
  else
    {
      rl_kill_text (rl_point, 0);
      rl_point = 0;
      if (rl_editing_mode == emacs_mode)
    rl_mark = rl_point;
    }
  return 0;
}

/* Kill backwards to the start of the line.  If DIRECTION is negative, kill
   forwards to the line end instead. */
int
rl_backward_kill_line (int direction, int key)
{
  int orig_point;

  if (direction < 0)
    return (rl_kill_line (1, key));
  else
    {
      if (rl_point == 0)
    rl_ding ();
      else
    {
      orig_point = rl_point;
      rl_beg_of_line (1, key);
      if (rl_point != orig_point)
        rl_kill_text (orig_point, rl_point);
      if (rl_editing_mode == emacs_mode)
        rl_mark = rl_point;
    }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found:

```
backward-kill-line (C-x Rubout)
    Kill backward to the beginning of the line.

unix-line-discard (C-u)
    Kill backward from the cursor to the beginning of the current line.
```

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bash-2.05a/html_node/bashref_97.html

```
       backward-kill-line (C-x Rubout)
              Kill backward to the beginning of the line.
       unix-line-discard (C-u)
              Kill backward from point to the beginning of the line.  The
              killed text is saved on the kill-ring.
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html#EDITING_COMMANDS

Seems that `unix-line-discard` saves it on the keyring, while `backward-kill-line` doesn't - however I couldn't find out how to verify that and the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackwardKillLine) says that `backward-kill-line` also appends to the jeyring

Other use of these terms: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/pull/489/files#diff-1fabf11f4aca2d62eb64290f66d25217R180